# How to open PDI v7 .1 transformation in.XML file repository format

Tags: xml, kettle

My company is using Enterprise Edition version 7.1 EE and an Enterprise Repository . I don't have access to this repository yet but I need to review some sample code . I got a code to review in a .XML file but Not .KTR or .KJB  . I need to open that in Spoon to review the Jobs and  Transformations inside . I tried to use the option in spoon to import from XML file but I get immediate error message  : " ///File _Repos.XML was not recognized as a Kettle file type ".   It is basically a repository file which is exported  in XML format I guess . How I open that again using spoon ? Do I have to install same Pentaho Version in my  client desktop  to be able to import ? is import to XML option is the right step ? if not , how I can open those XML files ( Not .KTR or .KJB )? and if it included jobs and transformation inside , will all this structures be opened properly ? I appreciate any one help in this please

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename the files as .kjb (if the first tag is ) or or .kjb (if the first tag is ).

It may be that your xml contains more than one transformation or kjb (as it used to be the case when you did an export from a database repository).

The directory structure of the contained transfo/jobs will be maintained only if the previous developer did his/her job correctly either

- by using references like ${Internal.Entry.Current.Directory}/load_dim.kjb, instead of the actual physical directory names ;
- if the actual physical directory structure is a copy of the logical directory in the repository.

Otherwise to reconstruct the ETL flow will be the first result of your job.

Comment: Then, please, accept the answer. Other users may face the same issue. And it increase ma reputation.